# Mouse Freezes On XOrg Load

Tags: 12.04, xorg, mouse, synaptic

Sorry to be a pain, but I'm joining the crowd of people who are experiencing mouse freezing/unresponisveness after upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.

On the login screen, I can move the mouse and type freely, there is no problem. However, as soon as my Desktop wallpaper image appears, the mouse and buttons no longer respond to input. The keyboard continues to work normally. Given that it works on the login screen but not the Desktop environment, I'm not sure whether or not this is an issue with X.Org - I've got no idea.

The mouse in concern is a built-in synaptic touchpad. Unfortunately, I don't have a handy USB or PS/2 mouse available.

**List of things that didn't work:**

- synclient TouchpadOff=0 (the mouse works on the login screen anyway, so the synaptics driver is loaded)
- Generating and replacing /etc/X11/xorg.conf
- sudo rmmod psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse
- Disabling irqbalance
- Restarting lightdm
- Replacing ~.gconf
- Reinstalling xserver-xorg-input-all

The output of **lspci -v**, **dmesg** and **synclient** are attached, in case they are of any use. I'm trying to avoid a fresh install, but I've backed everything up just in case.

- www.callummclean.cu.cc/stuff/dmesg.txt
- www.callummclean.cu.cc/stuff/synclient.txt
  (LSPCI in the next post)

Thanks in advance,

Cal McLean

Comment: LSPCI output: http://www.callummclean.cu.cc/stuff/lspci.txt

Comment: I've found a partial solution:
Uninstalling `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` will allow the mouse to move again (after Xorg restart), but at a price: the movement is unusually fast and slightly jittery. Also, some touchpad features are disabled, such as tapping to click and scrolling. It's a start though. I got this solution from here (and there are many more suggested if that doesn't work):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/549727

Comment: Righto =)
AU wouldn't let me as it was less than 8 hours after the question was posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I've found a working solution (as suggested here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/549727).

Editing the relevant Gnome variable with the command gconftool -s /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled -t boolean true seemed to work to an extent.

What really finished the trick was using sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps.

Some people have recommended just using sudo rmmod psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse. That didn't work, while the above command did. I don't know what those extra arguments do, but they work.

Oh, and it still works when xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is installed, so you can reinstall that if you've taken it out. Also, new versions of the xserver-* packages have just been released, so upgrading is probably a good idea. I have, and everything still works.

One restart later and my mouse is working perfectly.

Thanks to the folks on Launchpad.